# cannot login authentication laravel middleware

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

Every time I try to log in I always return to the login page i cant redirect to my dashboard.I have tried dd() and Auth::check and the results are all success

here my AuthController

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;

    public function loginProses(Request $request): RedirectResponse
    {
        $request->validate([
            'email'=>'required',
            'password'=>'required'
        ],[
            'email.required'=>'Email wajib diisi',
            'password.required'=>'Password wajib diisi',
        ]);

        $infologin = [
            'email'=>$request->email,
            'password'=>$request->password,
        ];

        if (Auth::attempt($infologin)) {
            $request->session()->regenerate();
            // if (Auth::check()) {
            //     return "success";
            // } else {
            //     return "not";
            // }
            return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
            // dd($infologin);
        }else{
            return redirect('/laravel')->withErrors('Username atau Password Salah')->withInput();
        }
    }
```

my DashboardController that I want to go to

```
use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Buku;
use App\Models\Kategori;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

    public function index()
    {
        $totalBooks = Buku::count();
        return view('backend.index', ['totalBooks' => $totalBooks]);
    }
```

my web Route

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\AuthController;
use App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController;
use App\Http\Controllers\BukuController;
use App\Http\Controllers\KategoriController;
use App\Http\Controllers\UsersController;

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function (){
    Route::resource('dashboard', \App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController::class);
    Route::resource('buku', \App\Http\Controllers\BukuController::class);
    Route::resource('kategori', \App\Http\Controllers\KategoriController::class);
    Route::delete('/logout', [AuthController::class, 'logout'])->name('logout');
});
```

I want to access the dashboard page that I gave the auth middleware

Answer (score 2):

I found my mistake, my id in my user table was called user_id, after I changed it to just id, finally after hours I was able to enter the dashboard.

Comment: Please use proper formatting to improve the readability of your answer.